# Placing an image from the sprite in the specific position

Tags: background, css, background-position

Let's say i have a sprite with lots of icons. I want to place one of the icons in the specific position over the div, e.g. 15px from the right side and 20px from the top.
Previously, when i had single image file i used the following code:

```
background: white url(./imgs/some/icon.png) no-repeat 91% 47%;
```

Now then the image is in the sprite i can access it using

```
background-position: 0 -471px;
```

But as i see it there is no place to add my current 91% 47%. Is there some kind of workaround?
It's possible to use CSS3 in the project if it helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be able to add another `<div>`, give it the correct background, and absolute position it where it needs to be? I'm thinking that your background-position percentages are probably out when you use a sprite sheet.

Comment: Yes, if there is no solution to do it without modifying code then i will have to add addition div and work with it.

Comment: If you don't have enough empty space around the icon (i.e. you see other icons in the sprite), you need the additional `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your set of constraints correctly, you might be able to pull it off with a single div, but only if your png has a transparent background and the icon has enough "transparent space" as to not reveal any other icons.

Try:

```
background: white url(./imgs/some/icon.png) 91% 47% no-repeat, transparent url(./imgs/some/icon.png) 0 -471px no-repeat;
```